Understanding Optimistic vs Pessimistic Concurrency Control in Real-World Use Cases
I'm having trouble understanding the difference between optimistic and pessimistic concurrency control when applied to real-world scenarios. Let's consider this example:
Scenario 1: Updating order details in a relational DB

User A retrieves the order details.
User B retrieves the same order details.
User A modifies the details.
User B modifies the details.
User A sends the updated data to the backend via a PUT API request.
Since this is a PUT request, the data is directly replaced in the database row.
User B sends their modified (older) data to the backend via the same PUT API.

With optimistic concurrency, the backend would check the version of the data before updating. Since User B's data has an outdated version, the update would be rejected.
However, I’m confused about how pessimistic concurrency could be applied to this situation. As I understand it, pessimistic concurrency involves locking the resource (e.g., row) during three steps: (1) retrieve, (2) modify, (3) persist. But in this scenario, only the persist step is executed on the backend (the data is modified on the client side).
Merging without replacing: If the user sends only the updated fields (similar to a PATCH request), the backend would merge these changes with the current version in the database before persisting. This makes sense if this is how it is working. But normally, we have to send the whole updated resource in a PUT method.
My questions:

Is there any point in using pessimistic concurrency here, given that the modification is done client-side?
Would pessimistic concurrency be more appropriate in scenarios where the data is modified directly on the backend (e.g., incrementing a bank account balance)?
For typical API interactions like the one above, where the data is modified on the client side and only updated via a PUT request, is optimistic concurrency generally a better approach?
What are the other use cases where pessimistic concurrency is used?

From what I understand, most real-world APIs tend to use optimistic concurrency. Pessimistic concurrency isn’t commonly applied in the context of REST API PUT methods.
